# How to revive nginx after it got beatup by stress testing

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, stress-testing, ab

## Background

I got two ec2 instances running laravel app on an nginx server behind a load balancer. We had the brilliant idea of running stress testing on the instances using apache ab like so:

```
 ab -c 350 -n 20000  -H "Accept:application/x.toters.v1+json" http://staging-load-balancer-2088007710.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api?store_ids[]=223%26lat=33.883666%26lon=35.533966
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking staging-load-balancer-2088007710.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com (be patient)
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 12000 requests
Completed 14000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 15912 requests completed
```

so it seems like it threw the towel near the end, running the stress tests again just dies immediately.

## Question

The problem is that now if we attempt to reach the instances (sidestepping the load balancer to isolate the problem) it just craps out, see the postman output:

[image]

and the nginx error logs show:

```
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120606 open socket #16 left in connection 163
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120629 open socket #34 left in connection 188
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120622 open socket #9 left in connection 213
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120628 open socket #25 left in connection 217
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120605 open socket #15 left in connection 244
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120614 open socket #41 left in connection 245
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120631 open socket #24 left in connection 255
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120616 open socket #23 left in connection 258
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: *120615 open socket #42 left in connection 269
2017/11/28 13:27:41 [alert] 321#321: aborting
```

restarting nginx didn't fix it, shutting down then turning on nginx didn't fix it. Ideas?

Comment: what system logs say? i.e. - dmesg command?

Answer (score 0):

After collecting any data from the test you want to keep, drain and destroy the instances and create new ones.

With a known good template for a scale out app, there is little need to fix an individual host. Unless perhaps you think there is a problem with its configuration or you want to take the time to learn.